# How to use MDC component in a AngularDart web app

Tags: forms, dart, material-design, angular-dart, mdc-components

I would like to integrate [this MDC](https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#usage) form in my web app. I’m using **AngularDart** (`5.0.0-beta+1`). [Here](https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/form-fields/) there is the **npm** line command to install this component (`npm install @material/form-field`).

Is there some way to use it in a **AngularDart** web app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The textfield is going to be a little difficult to wrap but there are a couple of ways you could do this.

- Load the mdc-web js and scss files in the index.html file and then create the necessary DOM structure in the component you want to have the element.
- Do something similar to what we do with material-card and place the Sass files in your dart package and reference them in your component. This isn't going to get you the JS parts of it tho. https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/tree/master/lib/material_card

angular_components will eventually provide a wrapper for this, but it isn't ready for release yet.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to do as you told.

Comment: More specifically, how can I follow the 1° way? Thanks!